# Answered Questions With Mistaken Calculation

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

Suppose I ask a question which includes a mistaken calculation, such that if the calculation were to be corrected, the question would be uninteresting.  The question receives an answer, indicating the mistake, and correctly solving the original equation.  This is the question I have in mind:  [Quadratic Formula With Independent and Dependent Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017691/quadratic-formula-with-independent-and-dependent-variables)

Editing the question by correcting the integration would eclipse the most interesting part, as the result is not quadratic.  Should the question be edited in a way that preserves the original mistake, as it currently does, or should the original differential equation be changed so that it does integrate to a quadratic equation, even though it would make the current answer invalid?

Comment: Leave the current question as is.  Accept the answer if it identified the problem you had answering that question.  There is nothing more frustrating than when an asker, after an answerer identifies their mistake, changes the question, rendering the answer invalid.  But if you have a different question that exemplifies a concern of yours, ask it as a new, separate question.

Comment: @amWhy I can think of plenty of more frustrating things.  :-)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Like someone taking a figure of speech literally? ;)

Answer (score 11):

Leave the question. In this case the question is interesting even after you correct the error.

Sometimes I see a question that is answered in a comment by pointing out a simple error that makes the question trivial or uninteresting. In that case I recommend that the OP delete it, since the question is unlikely to be useful to anyone else and should not remain on the unanswered queue attracting attention.